# Using SQL script through vb.net code

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am new to SQL Server.  I often find scripts over internet to perform different functions with SQL Server but I donot know how to use them in vb.net.

For example I want to run the following code through my vb.net application, but donot know how to do so.  Please advise

ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE ;
GO
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '' ;
GO

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code might help. Its from http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/code/216920

```vb
'Declare outside of class
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


'Declare inside of class >
Dim SQLStr As String
Private ConnString As String

'Connstring = Server Name, Database Name, Windows Authentication 
connstring = "Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=databasename;Integrated Security=True"

'SQL Staments

'SQL query = myQuery = "SQL Statment"

SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM tblQuestion"

SQLStr = "INSERT into tblQuestion(Name, Question) VALUES('Fred', 'How to use SQL?')"

SQLStr = "UPDATE tblQuestion SET Answer = 'Like this' Where Question = 'How to use SQL?'"

SQLStr = "DELETE FROM tblQuestion WHERE Question='How to use SQL?'"

'Write to SQL

Dim SQLConn As New SqlConnection() 'The SQL Connection
Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand() 'The SQL Command

SQLConn.ConnectionString = ConnString 'Set the Connection String
SQLConn.Open 'Open the connection

SQLCmd.Connection = SQLConn 'Sets the Connection to use with the SQL Command
SQLCmd.CommandText = SQLStr 'Sets the SQL String
SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 'Executes SQL Commands Non-Querys only

SQLConn.Close() 'Close the connection  









'Read from SQL

Dim SQLConn As New SqlConnection() 'The SQL Connection
Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand() 'The SQL Command
Dim SQLdr As SqlDataReader        'The Local Data Store

SQLConn.ConnectionString = ConnString 'Set the Connection String
SQLConn.Open 'Open the connection

SQLCmd.Connection = SQLConn 'Sets the Connection to use with the SQL Command
SQLCmd.CommandText = SQLStr 'Sets the SQL String
SQLdr = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader 'Gets Data

While dr.Read() 'While Data is Present        
      MsgBox(dr("Column Name")) 'Show data in a Message Box
End While

Loop While SQLdr.NextResult() 'Move to the Next Record
SQLdr.Close 'Close the SQLDataReader        

SQLConn.Close() 'Close the connection
```

Comment: The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t72t3k4.aspx) for the SQLClient library was an incredible help when I was trying to figure out how this stuff worked.